# Show that if $X$ is log-normally distributed, $Y = \ln(X)$ is normally distributed

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I've got this density function of a log-normal random variable.

$$f_X(x;\sigma)=\frac{1}{x\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{\ln(x)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

I'm trying to find the density function of $Y = \ln X$ and show that $Y$ is distributed $\operatorname{N}(0,\sigma^2)$.

I know the normal distribution is as follows:

$$f_X(x;\sigma)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

But I'm not sure how to proceed from the first equation to the second.

Any help appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Your book should have a formula for how to transform between random variables. What does it say?

Comment: @Arthur I'm not working from a textbook this is a question from a tutorial. Can you be more specific as to what your getting at?

Comment: @Arthur is the density function I'm looking for simply replacing $lnx$ with y and replacing x with $e^{y}$?

Comment: Almost. There is a correction involving the derivative of $y$, because of integration substitution. That's how to get rid of the $\frac1x$.

Comment: @Arthur I didn't use any integration. Just the fact that Y = lnx so $x = e^{y}$. Should I be integrating here?

Comment: Since the probability that $a<X<b$ should equal the probability that $\ln a<Y<\ln b$ for any $a,b$, and these two quantities have very much to do with integration, substitution rules come into this, yes.

Comment: I changed $f_x(x;\sigma)$ to $f_X(x;\sigma).$ There are good reason why one $X$ is capital and the other is in lower case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y=\ln X$, hence,
$$
F_Y(y) = P(Y\le y)=P(X\le e^y)=F_X(e^y),
$$
thus the density can be found as its derivative w.r.t $y$, i.e., 
$$
f_Y(y)=f_X(e^y)e^y=\frac{e^y}{e^y\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\exp\{-(\ln e^y)^2/(2\sigma^2)\} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\exp\{-y^2/(2\sigma^2)\},
$$
hence, $Y \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$.